# Should I PUT, POST and DELETE against the resource URL I made a GET request against if I requested a collection from a nested route?

Tags: rest

I have a question about designing REST APIs.

Lets say that `GET /schools/1/students` returns all students from a school with the id of 1.

Should `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` requests be sent to `/schools/1/students` to manipulate student resources going forward or to `/students`?

Answer (score 2):

GET all students - /schools/1/students
GET one student - /schools/1/students/:student_id
POST - create new student (/schools/1/students)
PUT - update ONE student (/schools/1/students/:student_id)
DELETE - delete ONE student (/schools/1/students/:student_id)

Comment: Is it common in a scenario like this to also provide a `/students` endpoint?  `POST /students` would do the same as `POST /schools/1/students` in my cases.

Comment: @guyja no, post /students endpoint not informative, because student belongs to school instance